# How to dynamically set gas price for faster transactions on Polygon using ethers.js or viem?

Tags: polygon

I am working on a project that involves interacting with the Polygon chain using ethers.js. I am facing challenges with slow transaction processing and would like to implement a solution to dynamically set the gas price for faster transactions, similar to the aggressive gas option available in MetaMask.

**I want to get the gas dynamic and pass it**